# Access protected properties via public method

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I'm testing a logic flow by mocking a class and testing for the function call.

```
function() setUp() 
{
    $this->shipping_method = $this->getMockBuilder(Wc_Trincargo_Shipping_Method::class)
                    ->getMock();

    $this->shipping_method->set_post_data([
        'woocommerce_wc-trinicargo-shipping_waybill_password' => 'xxx',
        'woocommerce_wc-trinicargo-shipping_waybill_username' => 'xxxx',
        'woocommerce_wc-trinicargo-shipping_waybill_customer_id' => uniqid(),
        'woocommerce_wc-trinicargo-shipping_waybill_pickupdays' => 2
    ]);
}
```

`set_post_data` is a public method that sets a **protected** property.

Later down I test to call a another method that needs to check the said **protected** property. I know they say you can't mock protected and private properties but if the properties are being set by public methods....shouldn't it work?

Comment: You should not know that the method sets protected properties at first place. This is kinda wrong. That's the internal implementation of the method and you should not be aware of it, when you test.

Comment: @RoyalBg not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: I'm trying to say that you test methods against business specification, not against the knowledge of the code behind. This is wrong. Imagine you are testing a compiled library and do not know the internal behavior of the code, you only know how it behaves dictated by the business.

Comment: initially I was testing the logic of the said method however the test was failing due to the said property not being set which was not really part of the test if that makes any sense

Comment: You need to isolate the dependencies this method have in order to run a real `unit test`. Your test fails because some other dependencies do not work properly. Test them separately and "mock" them here. If you cannot isolate the dependencies then the architecture is most probably wrong.

Comment: I'm testing woo commerce extensions. Not even sure how possible that is given that i need to have it in order to have the correct environment to test.

Comment: oh, this is completely different. Check if there is specialzed framework for testing woocommerce. They themselves have tests in the project - check how do they do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to access a protected property within a test and you don't have a getter (nor should you create one purely for a test), you could use reflection.

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    protected $myProperty;

    public function setMyProperty($value) 
    {
        $this->myProperty = $value;
    }
}


$a = new MyClass();
$a->setMyProperty('TestValue');

// echo $a->myProperty; Can't do this because it's protected.

$r = new ReflectionProperty('MyClass', 'myProperty');
$r->setAccessible(true);
$value = $r->getValue($a);

echo $value; // 'TestValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant that the **protected** property was sat from a **public** method. The visibility belongs to the property regardless. If you need to check the value of the property afterwards, create a public getter for that property.

Note that it is useless to test simple getters and setters. You should test what the class does with the values of the properties instead.

Example of a useless test:

```
class MyClass {
    private $prop;
    public function setProp($value) {
        $this->prop = $value;
    }
    public function getProp() {
        return $this->prop;
    }
}
```

Test

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->setProp('foo');
assertTrue($myClass->getProp() === 'foo');
```

Example of a class that *uses* a prop in a meaningful way, which determines the behavior/output of another method:

```
class MyClass2 {
    private $prop;
    public function setProp($value) {
        $this->prop = $value;
    }
    public function getPropUpperCase() {
        return strtoupper($this->prop);
    }
}
```

Test

```
$myClass2 = new MyClass();
$myClass2->setProp('foo');
assertTrue($myClass->getPropUpperCase() === 'FOO');
```

Comment: Changing a class definition to meet the needs of a test seems like the wrong thing to do to me. If there wasn't a `getX()` for this property and its set to protected, there is most likely a reason why that was done. Adding an extra method purely so he can access it within a test isn't really something advisable. If there isn't a reason, then obviously just add a getter, it's the simplest solution.

Comment: @Pigeon The premise of the test is flawed either way. What is the need of checking a property value if it is protected after being sat by a public setter? The tests are laid out all wrong.

Comment: If you subscribe to the idea of TDD, then you have to write a tests to implement accessors and mutators. If you don’t subscribe to the idea of TDD, then writing tests for accessors and mutators might prove the absence of defects.

Comment: @localheinz In some weird edge case that might be the case, but you could otherwise make that field immutable and only allow to set it once. When you test your actual functionality, the output of _that_ function would reflect the value of the property. Reflector classes are generally avoided unless it is the last option. My point was that testing the value of a (hidden) property itself it useless. What that property is used _for_ is what is supposed to be tested. Subscribing to TDD does not mean creating unit tests or mocks for every single property in a class.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I'm not testing the get or set properties I;m actually testing a method that does some other stuff but checks and retrieves the protected property in the process which is vital for the execution of the rest of the logic

Comment: if it retrieves the property, check the result of the method then

Comment: @Kendall Your question here seem like a x for y problem. You can use reflector classes to do what you want, or you could state your _actual_ problem, because it seem like your architecture has some flaws.

Comment: @OptimusCrime well my problem is that I needed to have the protected property set in order for the method in question to be used so that I can test the method results. The method results are failing because of this which was kinda outside the scope of the initial test condition.